# how can i make my page refresh only once?

Tags: javascript, refresh, settimeout, onload

Js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function timedRefresh(timeoutPeriod) {

  var refreshed=true;

  if(refreshed){

    refreshed=false;

    setTimeout("location.reload();",timeoutPeriod);
  }

}
</script>
```

Html

body onload="JavaScript:timedRefresh(5000);"

i can not get it to load only once its keeps reloading instead of taking the new value

Comment: you realise the page starts again when it loads?

Answer (score 1):

Reloading the page will trigger the load event again, that will again reload the page ...
You should use cookies or other client-side data storage to know if the page has already been loaded once.

Comment: I figured thats what it was

Answer (score 1):

You are making the assumption that the browser is keeping the javascript variable values between each page load, but everything is flushed. You might want to use HTML5 local storage so that state is persisted between pages.

See http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp